# Aruch HaShulchan on not saying certain phrases in hallel when davening alone

Tags: tefilla, hallel, aruch-hashulchan

The Aruch HaShulchan 422:9 says someone davening alone should not say "ki l'olam chasdo" after "yomar na yisrael."  Then he seems to say the same, that one shouldn't say "ki l'olam chasdo" after the other phrases in that section.  Is he saying that a yachid would still say the phrases before the phrase "ki l'olam chasdo"?  But in that case it wouldn't really make sense, because he is just saying that these people are saying "blank" and not saying what they are saying.  Can someone who reads Hebrew please read Aruch HaShulchan 422:9 and tell me exactly what he says?   https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.422.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: Actually forget what I wrote.  I think he is actually just saying the yachid doesn't say "hodu laShem ki tov."  But he would say "ki l'olam chasdo" after each phrase.

Comment: But would a yachid according to the Aruch HaShulchan still say "hodu laShem ki tov ki l'olam chasdo" at the beginning of that section, since that is the first posuk in that section?

Comment: He's saying not to say the responses. Like how when you say Kiddush for yourself you don't say amen.

Comment: @DoubleAA are the responses "hodu lashem ki tov ki l'olam chasdo"?  And would you still say that phrase as the first verse in that series of verses, but you just wouldn't repeat it?  And if this is what he is saying, why does he mention "hodu lashem ki tov ki l'olam chasdo" last, when it is the first in order?

Comment: The customary way in European based communities to say Hallel publicly is for the leader to recite each of the first four verses of psalm 118 aloud for the congregation, and for the congregants to recite הודו לה' כי טוב כי לעולם חסדו as a response to each. Without a leader to say the main text on your behalf, you say it yourself and skip the responses, just as you would with Kiddush alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> דבר פשוט הוא שכשאומר הלל ביחיד לא יאמר בהודו אחר יאמר נא ישראל ויאמרו נא בית אהרן ויאמרו נא יראי ד' הודו לד' כי טוב דזה אינו אלא בציבור או לפחות כשהם שלושה דאחד אומר יאמר נא והשנים משיבים ולא כשהוא יחידי ואפילו שנים אינם כלום אלא אם כן הם שלושה שאחד אומר והשנים משיבים
>
> It is an obvious matter that when one says Hallel alone he should not say in "הודו" after "יאמר נא ישראל" and "יאמרו נא בית אהרן" and "'יאמרו נא יראי ד" [the refrain of] "הודו לד' כי טוב", because that is only with a congregation, or at least when there are three [people], for [then] one would say "יאמר נא" and the [other] two would respond. But not when he is alone, and even two [people] do not count, unless there are three [people] where one says and two respond.

In other words, when praying with a congregation, the leader would recite the line "יאמר נא ישראל" and the congregation would respond to that with "הודו לד' כי טוב". The Aruch Hashulchan is saying that this only works when there is a congregation (or at least three people) such that one person can say the main line and the rest can respond with the "הודו" line. But if you're praying by yourself you don't respond to yourself, so you would just say "יאמר נא ישראל" and then go on to "יאמרו נא בית אהרן" without saying "הודו" in between.

Comment: Would a yachid still say the first line, which is "hodu lashem ki tov ki l'olam chasdo"?

Comment: @talk he says all the lines but none of the responses.